# .net Dataset Primary-Keys - enforcing uniqueness?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset, primary-key

I have a small dataset with a few datatables.  I load the datatables from various DBs and have a config file that I read to determine the primary keys I want to enforce on the given datatables.  If the config doesn't contain a proper (non unique) primary key, how can I catch this event when applying the primary key to the datatable?  Currently it appears that it allows me to apply the primary key, even though it is not unique....

```
       DataTable dtbl = ds.Tables[t.tblname];

       DataColumn[] pks = new DataColumn[t.Get_Key_Columns().Count];
       int i = 0;
        foreach(DataColumn c in dtbl.Columns)
        {
            if(t.Get_Key_Columns().Exists(delegate(App_Column ac) 
                  {return (ac.column_name == c.ColumnName);}))
            {
                pks[i] = c;
                i++;
            }
        }
        try
        {
            dtbl.PrimaryKey = pks; 
        } 
         catch etc.......
```

Anyone point out what I am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about adding them as a constraint?

```
dt.Constraints.Add("PKC", Columns, true)
```

If that still allows duplicates, does the .HasErrors property provide any indication?

---

**Edit** from the comments:

What ultimately worked for OP was this work-around: add the constraints *before* filling the table.

Comment: try {
                UniqueConstraint uc = new UniqueConstraint("pk",pks, true);
                dtbl.Constraints.Add(uc);
            }
I checked HasErrors and its false after each table has their PK applied.  (checked the Dataset and DataTable properties)....  I even call AcceptChanges()...

Comment: The dataset gets filled from the datasource, and then I apply the keys.. is there some property on the dataset that I need to set to enable
 the constraints?

Comment: can you insert a duplicate *after* the primary key is applied?

Comment: working on doing building the dataset schema - then apply the keys - then load data to try that out...

Comment: I used Fill_Schema first, applied the PKs and then do the fill and its throwing an exception - thanks...

Comment: Great, glad it's "working" now. Too bad you had to do all that rework.